# Using Microsoft.Graph Calendar Event and Sensitivity

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

According to documentation for a *Outlook Calendar* **Event** the **Sensitivity** can be:

```
//
// Summary:
//     The enum Sensitivity.
[JsonConverter(typeof(EnumConverter))]
public enum Sensitivity
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     normal
    Normal = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     personal
    Personal = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     private
    Private = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     confidential
    Confidential = 3
}
```

So, I code it like this:

```
Sensitivity = oData.Settings.SetCalendarPrivate ? Sensitivity.Private : Sensitivity.Normal
```

Yet, when you actually log into the web Outlook client, an event looks like this in the interface:

[image: Set Private Option]

It is just a tick box. So why is it not a drop list?

How are the other settings used? And what is the impact if the calendar gets shared with others?

Comment: http://windowsitpro.com/outlook/outlook-using-sensitivity-levels-appointments - _"Private is the only sensitivity setting that has any appointment-related functionality. Setting an appointment's or meeting request's Sensitivity property to Personal or Confidential has no effect. Perhaps that's why Outlook provides only a Private check box on the Appointment form and not a Sensitivity drop-down list like the one on a message's Options dialog box."_

Comment: @stuartd Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Outlook client has the ability to set the other properties. A lot of the properties in the Graph API related to events originate from the properties that are present in Exchange server, even though they may not be visible in the Calendar web interface.

In Outlook the UI for changing the Sensitivity is in the File/Properties when the appointment window is open:

[image: appointment properties window]